# Problem with my tiny icing particles on the donut

Tags: modeling, mesh, geometry-nodes

I'm a complete noob to 3d software. I took the Blender Guru's tutorial and finished it once before. Now I am doing it again but by myself going back to things I found hurdles in, ie the geometry node segment.

My problem is that the cylinder is appearing but they are microscopic. Any ideas would be appreciated. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its likely that the problem here is that the cylinder has been scaled and that scale has not been applied. Select the cylinder, press CTRL-A, and select "Scale"

[image: Apply Scale]

[image: Applied Scale]

Hopefully that will fix it, You could also check the relative box on the object info node but that will take into account the position of the cylinder as well so you'd have to move it to the origin.

Comment: i applied the scale and it gave me the image i showed  i think the problem was i went into shading  and applied some nodes to the icing ? im really lost so far it looks good but the sprinkles are a kill joy

Comment: You could try applying the scale on the donut as well in case that is off. I wouldn't expect it to be a shading issue since your screenshot shows the problem in solid view and a shading issue would only appear in rendered or rendered preview.

Comment: YOU ARE A GOD THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: @AustinMgbolu If the answer was helpful please accept it or upvote useful answers. This helps other users that have a similar question to find a solution for their problem.

Answer (score 0):

What [@Stoat Paws](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/146967/stoat-paws) mentioned is likely the solution, also it's possible that you're modeling your donut at an enormous scale. Make sure that the object dimensions resemble something like a real life size for both the donut and the sprinkles, or at least something realistic relative to eachother.

[image]

That or check the scale value in the particle system if that's how you're distributing the sprinkles.

[image]